# Getting a Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error With no error code number

Tags: c#, .net, forms, visual-studio

I looked at the other similar question, and it seems to be different from my problem. I have also checked Microsoft date sheets as well a google all the phrases I could think of.

The error is as follows:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "ResolveComReference" task returned false but did not log an error. OpenDataSheet

What I am trying to do is open a Workbook and get the number of sheets; I will then hopefully load a combo box with the names.

Attached is the code.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "ResolveComReference" task returned false but did not log an error. OpenDataSheet

I removed the extra "," at the end, but that did not fix anything.

I am now getting the following warnings.

I can not find a DTSlib.

Warning     Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "DTSLib". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component.
For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.

Warning     The referenced component 'DTSLib' could not be found.

Warning     Could not resolve dependent COM reference "ff6681cd-490a-498c-b8c9-81223b6056fc" version 1.0.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace OpenDataSheet
{
    public partial class FrmOpenDataSheet : Form
  
    {

        public FrmOpenDataSheet()
        {
            Excel.Application app;
            Excel.Workbook foodPantryWorkbook;
            Excel.Worksheet workSheet;

            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            //this.Application.Workbooks.Open(@"Food Pantry Registry.xlsm");

            app = new Excel.Application();
            foodPantryWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Open("Food Pantry Registry.xlsm", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            //string proc = "RegisterInput.exe";
            //Process.Start(proc);
            workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)foodPantryWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Totals");
            int numberOfSheets = foodPantryWorkbook.Sheets.Count;
            int temp = 0;
            temp += temp;
        }

        private void CmdCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string proc = "Food Pantry.exe";
            Process.Start(proc);
            System.Environment.Exit(0);

        }

        private void CmdSelectSheet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Solved with the following code:

Comment: Solved with the following code

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by specifying the complete patch from drive c: onwards. Evidently, even if the file is in the same folder as your executable file you still have to specify the complete path.